# automating inputing data for a webpage

Tags: javascript, web, automation

Suppose there are 3 web pages, page `A`,page `B` and page `C`.

**Page A**:

This page only has a URL to page B.

**Page B**

This is the page that asks for user-name and password for access to Page C.

**Page C**

This is the page with some random user specific data.

**Question:**

If I know the user-name and password ,how can go from Page `A` to `C` directly without having to manually enter in the details at Page `B`.

I am assuming that I have no idea about how(GET,POST) input parameters are passed from Page `B`. How can I automate this task (for example using javascript ). Using any automation tool for such small task would be overkill.

Comment: set a session variable and on page b check for session variable and based on it, keep the user on page b or redirect the user to page c

Comment: or a cookie. It's not overkill when it is necessary

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:                                                                                                               [page 1]-

```
<script>
function assignwebStorage()
{
var a=document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
var b=document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1].value;
if((a!=null&&a!="")&&(b!=null&&b!=""))
{
localStorage.username=a;
localStorage.password=b;//aware
}    
}
</script>
<form action="page2.htm" onsubmit="assignwebStorage()">
Username:<input type="text"></input><br>
Password:<input type="password"></input><br>
<input type="submit" value="Proceed"></input></form>
```

[page 2]-

```
<script>
if(typeof localStorage.username=="undefined" && typeof localStorage.password=="undefined")
{
document.write("<form action='page3.htm' onsubmit='assignvalue()'>Username:<input type='text'></input><br>Password:<input type='password'></input><br><input type='submit' value='Submit'></input></form>");
function assignvalue()
{
localStorage.username=document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
localStorage.password=document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1].value;
}
}
else
{
window.location.replace("page3.htm")
}
</script>
```

[page 3]-

```
<body style="background:black">
<script>
//use webStorage variables anywhere but after that
delete localStorage.username;
delete localStorage.password;
//if any time user directly opens file 2 without opening file1
</script>
</body>
```

It will surely solve your problem.

Comment: You can use sessionStorage in place of localStorage in this case.It would be better as you wont need to use delete prop as in page3